# Why mse decreases while cosine similarity fluctuates?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, correlation, predictive-models

I am using deep neural networks to predict continuous variables, and I always get that:

1. the mse of both the training and validation almost keeps decreasing smoothly;
2. the cosine similarity between the prediction and label of the training increases smoothly;
3. while, the cosine similarity between the prediction and label of the validation increases but with large fluctuation.

I cannot figure out why point 3 happens, and I seldom find this phenomenon when using boosting tree methods.